# How to Change Variation Drop-down to link option WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

How to Change Variation Drop-down to link option WooCommerce?

say, if attributes equal to new-services, then when new services are selected from the Variation Drop-down, it goes to new services page.

similar like below:

```
select onChange="window.location.href=this.value">
option value="www.google.com">A</option>
option value="www.google.com">B</option>
/select
```

Comment: try with:

`<option <?php if(attribute){ echo 'selected'; } ?> value="www">A</option>`

Comment: not working , thanks!